# Question about exercise 22.14 in TeXbook

Tags: alignment

The answer to this exercise is:

```
$$\vbox{\tabskip=0pt \offinterlineskip
\halign to 36em{\tabskip=0pt plus1em#&
#\hfil&#&#\hfil&#&#\hfil&#\tabskip=0pt\cr
&&&&&\strut J. H. B\"ohning, 1838&\cr
&&&&\multispan3\hrulefill\cr
&&&\strut M. J. H. B\"ohning, 1882&\vrule\cr
&&\multispan3\hrulefill\cr
&&\vrule&&\vrule&\strut M. D. Blase, 1840&\cr
&&\vrule&&\multispan3\hrulefill\cr
&\strut L. M. Bohning, 1912&\vrule\cr
\multispan3\hrulefill\cr
&&\vrule&&&\strut E. F. Ehlert, 1845&\cr
&&\vrule&&\multispan3\hrulefill\cr
&&\vrule&\strut P. A. M. Ehlert, 1884&\vrule\cr
&&\multispan3\hrulefill\cr
&&&&\vrule&\strut C. L. Wischmeyer, 1850&\cr
&&&&\multispan3\hrulefill\cr}}$$
\end
```

However, if we change the line

```
\multispan3\hrulefill\cr
```

into

```
\multispan3\hrulefill\vrule\cr
```

the result is different (and more correct). Why?

Comment: Visually the outcome is the same with or without your change. Why do you think that adding `\vrule` makes the result 'more correct' (and what does that mean)?

Comment: I tried typesetting the `\vbox` inside `\rlap` and then typesetting the same `\halign` with `\multispan3\hrulefill\vrule\cr` replacing `\multispan3\hrulefill\cr`. I can see no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me add some colors to show the difference between the cases without and with `\vrule` added. The code:

```
\input miniltx
\input color.sty

$$\vbox{\tabskip=0pt \offinterlineskip
\halign to 36em{\tabskip=0pt plus1em#&
#\hfil&#&#\hfil&#&#\hfil&#\tabskip=0pt\cr
&&&&&\strut J. H. B\"ohning, 1838&\cr
&&&&\multispan3{\color{blue}\hrulefill}\cr
&&&\strut M. J. H. B\"ohning, 1882&\vrule\cr
&&\multispan3{\color{blue}\hrulefill}\cr
&&\vrule&&\vrule&\strut M. D. Blase, 1840&\cr
&&\vrule&&\multispan3{\color{blue}\hrulefill}\cr
&\strut L. M. Bohning, 1912&\vrule\cr
\multispan3\hrulefill\vrule\cr
&&\vrule&&&\strut E. F. Ehlert, 1845&\cr
&&\vrule&&\multispan3{\color{blue}\hrulefill\color{red}\vrule}\cr
&&\vrule&\strut P. A. M. Ehlert, 1884&\vrule\cr
&&\multispan3{\color{blue}\hrulefill\color{red}\vrule}\cr
&&&&\vrule&\strut C. L. Wischmeyer, 1850&\cr
&&&&\multispan3{\color{blue}\hrulefill\color{red}\vrule}\cr}}$$
\end
```

I've added red `\vrule`s to the lower branch, but used the original code (except for the blue color) for the upper branch. Here are the two forks magnified:

- The upper one:
  [image]
- The lower one:
  [image]

As you can see, the `\hrulefill` happily uses all three columns width and fills the gap between two black vertical lines at the first image. At the second image there's an additional `\vrule` (tiny red square) which doesn't do any harm but seems unnecessary.

Similar effect can be observed at the very end of the branches:

- The upper one:
  [image]
- The lower one:
  [image]

The total length of the rules are the same, so visually there would be no difference if the rules were rendered black. (Their length seem to differ at the image because I've cropped the pictures by hands.)

So since the results are the same, I'd prefer the shorter solution from the TeXbook.

Comment: @egreg I tried with `dvips` - `.ps` files differ slightly (I guess you tried `pdftex` - with it I have identical output too). What is more curious is why the `\hbox` for this rule has zero width, although `glue set ...` is present for it: `\hbox(0.4+0.0)x0.0, glue set 110.77058fill`. Is it typical for all `\hrulefill`s and/or other boxes? (that glue is set but width is zero)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the difference of first and second version, obtained via `dv2dt`:

```
@@ -124 +124,2 @@
-sr 26214 7285673
+sr 26214 7259459
+sr 26214 26214
```

We see that `7285673` is exactly equal to `7259459+26214`. So, where is the problem?

If we compare the output of `dvitype`, we get this:

```
@@ -249,3 +249,5 @@
-439: setrule height 26214, width 7285673 (4x923 pixels) 
- h:=3596434+7285673=10882107, hh:=1379 
-448: pop 
+439: setrule height 26214, width 7259459 (4x920 pixels) 
+ h:=3596434+7259459=10855893, hh:=1376 
+448: setrule height 26214, width 26214 (4x4 pixels) 
+ h:=10855893+26214=10882107, hh:=1380 
+457: pop
```

So we see that although widths in DVI file are equivalent, the resulting pixel output differs by one pixel (`923` vs. `920+4`).